# looping through dates in hp unix via arthmatic operations

Tags: linux, perl, unix

Hello i am using hp unix, i am trying to loop through the last 20 days (with respect to the current date) using a for loop .

```
for (( c=1; c<=5; c++ ))
do
day$c=$(perl -e 'use POSIX;print strftime "%Y%m%d\n",localtime time-86400*$c;')
done
later do some operations with day$c
```

issue is that for some strange reason 86400*$c is not executing , can any one point out the mistake ? thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try different quoting:

```
day$c=$(perl -e "use POSIX;print strftime qq(%Y%m%d\n),localtime time-86400*$c;")
```

(I'm not familiar with HPUX, but it looks like `$c` isn't getting interpolated by the shell.)

Edit: Or the slightly shorter:

```
day$c=$(perl -MPOSIX -le "print strftime '%Y%m%d',localtime time-86400*$c;")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use spaces in between operator and operands

```
perl -e 'use POSIX; print strftime "%Y%m%d\n",localtime time - 86400 * $c;'
```

Comment: no thats not the issue have tried , it still out puts the current date 5 times !

Comment: I didn't notice HPUX right there!! If you could tell me what is the need of using this perl here, I could try finding out what I could do :)

Comment: using perl is not necessary , i just want to loop through the last 20 dates one by one .                                                perl -e 'use POSIX; print strftime "%Y%m%d\n",localtime time - 86400 ' run perfectly fine for day-1 so i am trying to use it , if you have any other suggestion i would love them